# Search for way to save picture in predefined location with png(), similar to successful approach using ggsave()

Tags: r, png

I am using two different kinds of graphics: 1.) a boxplot created with ggplot2 and 2.) a correlation table.

I want to save both graphics under a location that can be chosen by the user through a prompt, using:

```
library(easycsv)
choose_dir = function(){
    os = Identify.OS()
    if(tolower(os) == "windows"){
        directory <- utils::choose.dir()
    }
    if(tolower(os) == "macosx"){
        system("osascript -e 'tell app \"RStudio\" to POSIX path of (choose folder with prompt \"Choose Folder:\")' > /tmp/R_folder",
        intern = FALSE, ignore.stderr = TRUE)
        directory <- system("cat /tmp/R_folder && rm -f /tmp/R_folder", intern = TRUE)
    }
    return(directory)
}
```

Now, I am using this code to choose the location I want to save the graphics in:

```
folder = choose_dir()
```

To save my graphics, I have no issue with the boxplot using ggsave:

```
ggsave("SL_Boxplot.png", path = folder, width=7, height= 0.7, dpi=500, units = "cm", scale = 5.2)
```

However, I am unable to save the correlation table picture in the same way as with ggsave, even though I tried many different ways:

```
png("folder/Correlation_Table.png", width = 30, height = 25, pointsize = 8, res = 700, units = "cm")
```

nothing works. Very grateful for anyone helping out!

Comment: It's not entirely clear from your code, but one clear distinction between `ggsave` and `png` is that the former is called after the plot has been built, but `png` must be called before the canvas is even started. That is, something like `png(...); boxplot(...); other_plotting_functions; dev.off()` is the normal `png` sequence of commands.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I was abiding by this rule - so I first use png() and then after the plot ran I use dev.off(). However, it does not work with the "folder"-location. Everything's fine with ggsave, but I cannot use it for saving the correlation table unfortunately ...

Comment: Seems like your main problem is that you need the value of `folder` in your png file name, not the letters f, o, l, d, e, r. `png(filename = paste(folder, "Correlation_Table.png", sep = "/"), ...)`. Or `png(filename = "%s/Correlation_table.png", folder), ...)` if you prefer "fill-in-the-blank" to "paste-it-together" syntax.

Comment: Sweet, that does the trick @Gregor ! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a valid path for `png`.

```
png(paste0(folder,"/Correlation_Table.png"), width = 30, height = 25, pointsize = 8, res = 700, units = "cm")
```

You can also change `/` to `\\`.

**Edits:** to be more proper and safe, this is the correct code provided by @r2evans.

```
png(file.path(folder, "Correlation_Table.png"), width = 30, height = 25, pointsize = 8, res = 700, units = "cm")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Gregor's comment does it more "correctly" by using `paste(..., sep="/")` (which is effectively `file.path(..., fsep="/")`, though `file.path` is roughly 33% faster), whereas you hard-code it into the filename. Though I suspect it'll work, it's making assumptions that may not always be true. (Windows often prefers the backslash, and while on my win-system it will accept both, I'm not 100% certain that it *always everywhere* accepts the forward slash as well.)

Comment: @r2evans, thanks for pointing that out. Do you know of an alternative to avoid that possibility (of windows not recognising the forward slash)?

Comment: I think the only "proper" safe way is to use `file.path` and don't override `fsep`. This would make your code `png(file.path(folder, "Correlation_Table.png"), ...)`, a drop-in replacement. (I say this knowing full well that while debugging code interactively, I tend to force `fsep="/"` since it always works for me and I find the (escaped-)backslash on the R console to be an eye-sore.)

Comment: I've always wondered if it would be fruitful to write an R-equivalent to python's [`Pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), where they've over-written the division-operator so that you could instead do `png(folder / "Correlation_Table.png", ...)`, where `/` is a special infix operator that really just concats with `fsep`.

Comment: I like that idea. But I'd prefer a plus sign `+`.

Comment: A little late back to this discussion but very impressed how you guys always have another option available - works, thank you very much!